# Durandal widget and viewModel binding context issue

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

we are developing an application with Durandal and I have run into a bit of a problem and for some reason cannot figure out a way to get this to work.

The problem: My main view model binding context and the widget context are completely separate. The data displays just fine, but it is static and I cannot perform the click functionality such as adding tasks, new task lists, etc (The parent is the Project and $data is the widget object functions). However if I create a "new task list" it's content can be manipulated via it's parent (the widget controller). I need to be able to manipulate the initial data displayed as we well as any created lists (all newly created lists can add tasks, and so on). For some reason I cannot figure out how to make this happen.

In the project view markup list of data is a widget called as follows:

```
<section data-bind="tasklists: { items: project.task_lists }"></section>
```

The task list widget view is:

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: settings.items } -->
<div data-bind="text: title" class="task-list-title"></div>
<div class="widget-task-list">
    <!-- ko foreach: { data: tasks } -->
        <li class="task-list-item">
            <input type="checkbox" class="task-list-checkbox" data-bind="checked: completed, attr: { id: 'task-check' + id() + $index() }">

            <label data-bind="text: title, attr: { for: 'task-check' + id() + $index() }"></label>
            <span data-bind="text: comment_count " class="comments-count"></span>

            <span class="pill assigned">
                <!-- ko if: assigned_to -->
                <span data-bind="text: assigned_to"></span>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <span> - </span>
                <!-- ko if: due_date -->
                <span data-bind="time: due_date"></span>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </span>

            <span data-bind="text: 'PROJECT TAG'" class="tag-teal"></span>
            <span data-bind="bootstrapPopover: {} " class="pill">Popover</span>
        </li>
    <!-- /ko -->

    <input type="checkbox" class="task-list-checkbox">
    <input data-bind="click: $data.enableTyping, value: $data.newTask" placeholder="Add a task to this list" type="text" class="add-task">
    <span data-bind="bootstrapPopover: {}, text: 'Unassigned' " class="pill"></span>
    <!-- <span data-bind="widget: { kind: 'popover' } "></span> -->
    <span data-bind="text: 'Due Date'" class="pill"></span>
    <div data-bind="visible: $data.isTyping" class="task-action-buttons-holder">
        <button class="button button-add" data-bind="click: $data.addTask, text: 'Add Task' "></button>
        <button class="button button-cancel" data-bind="click: '', text: 'Cancel' "></button>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

And the project model is as follows:

```
  return {
    activate: function(data) {
        var project_loading = cache.getItem('project', Number(data.id));
        var self = this;

        $.when(project_loading).done(function(project) {
            self.project = new Project(project);
            self.project.load();
        });

        return project_loading;
    }
};
```

And finally the project binding context:

```
["Binding", "views/projects/single", Object]
0: "Binding"
1: "views/projects/single"
2: Object
__moduleId__: "viewmodels/projects/single"
activate: function (data) {
project: Project
__proto__: Object
length: 3
__proto__: Array[0]
```

All I need to do is be able to manipulate the initial data in the project task lists view and make the binding contexts for the project and widget the same. Is this possible? I feel like I'm over thinking it. Any help is greatly appreciated.